# How to format a date/datime having optional separator and date string C#

Tags: c#, date, datetime, date-formatting

I´m giving the user the power to choose the date format and the date separator that will be used.

So i have two text boxes, in one you get de dateTime format ( can be only date or datetime) and on the other a date separator,
Note: time will always have ':' separator

eg textBox1:

> yyyyMMdd hhmmss

or

> hhmm ddMM

or

> ddyyyy hhmm

eg:textbox2 it will be introduzed one of the following separators /, -, _, .

The result i need is something like separator-> / and date string yyyyMMdd hhmmss

2022/05/26 05:39:24

I got a method that returns 20220526 053924 but with no separators

```
private string DateFormated(string dateFormat)
{            
   String dts = DateTime.Now.ToString(dateFormat, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
   DateTime.ParseExact(dts, dateFormat, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
 
   return dts;
 }
```

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/custom-date-and-time-format-strings

Comment: As far i understod, the example u gave me, is good for formatting date , that we now in advanced the format (string pattern = "MM-dd-yy";) In this case I don´t , and i need to build from the scrach

Answer (score 0):

you can use multiple conditions or just store format and separator in string and pass over "yyyyMMdd" and "yyyy-MM-dd" in below example.

```
String dts = DateTime.ParseExact(dateString, "yyyyMMdd", null).ToString("yyyy-MM-dd");
```

Furthermore, you can refer this site for more examples on date parsing https://www.dotnetperls.com/datetime-format

Comment: But if I don´t know the  separator or the format in advanced, will I have to repeat the code multiple times, whether the separator is "/"or "-" or "_" ?? 
Or even if the format is "yyyyMMdd" or "ddMMyyyy" ??